# Panel being shown under grid scrollbar

Tags: delphi

I'm using windows 10 theme in my project, and i've have noticed that: Panels that are positioned on edges of grids, they're shown under the grid scrollbar, 
like this image:

[image]

I haven't changed any behavior of the VCL, or the grid or scroll behavior.

pas file:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Data.DB, Vcl.StdCtrls,
  Datasnap.DBClient, Vcl.Grids, Vcl.DBGrids, Vcl.ExtCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Panel1: TPanel;
    DbGrid: TDBGrid;
    Panel2: TPanel;
    ClientDataSet: TClientDataSet;
    DataSource1: TDataSource;
    ButtonAdd: TButton;
    ShowPanel: TButton;
    ClientDataSetname: TStringField;
    ClientDataSetaddress: TStringField;
    procedure ButtonAddClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ShowPanelClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.ButtonAddClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ClientDataset.Append;
  ClientDataSetname.AsString := 'Test name';
  ClientDataSetaddress.AsString := 'Test address';
  ClientDataset.Insert;
end;

procedure TForm1.ShowPanelClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Panel2.Visible then
     Panel2.Visible := False
  else
    Panel2.Visible := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ClientDataset.CreateDataSet;
end;

end.
```

dfm file:

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 201
  ClientWidth = 555
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object Panel1: TPanel
    Left = 460
    Top = 0
    Width = 95
    Height = 201
    Align = alRight
    TabOrder = 0
    object ButtonAdd: TButton
      Left = 10
      Top = 16
      Width = 75
      Height = 25
      Caption = 'ButtonAdd'
      TabOrder = 0
      OnClick = ButtonAddClick
    end
    object ShowPanel: TButton
      Left = 10
      Top = 47
      Width = 75
      Height = 25
      Caption = 'ShowPanel'
      TabOrder = 1
      OnClick = ShowPanelClick
    end
  end
  object DbGrid: TDBGrid
    Left = 0
    Top = 0
    Width = 460
    Height = 201
    Align = alClient
    DataSource = DataSource1
    TabOrder = 1
    TitleFont.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
    TitleFont.Color = clWindowText
    TitleFont.Height = -11
    TitleFont.Name = 'Tahoma'
    TitleFont.Style = []
    Columns = <
      item
        Expanded = False
        FieldName = 'name'
        Visible = True
      end
      item
        Expanded = False
        FieldName = 'address'
        Visible = True
      end>
  end
  object Panel2: TPanel
    Left = 0
    Top = 160
    Width = 185
    Height = 41
    Caption = 'panel2'
    TabOrder = 2
    Visible = False
  end
  object ClientDataSet: TClientDataSet
    Aggregates = <>
    Params = <>
    Left = 216
    Top = 104
    object ClientDataSetname: TStringField
      FieldName = 'name'
      Size = 50
    end
    object ClientDataSetaddress: TStringField
      FieldName = 'address'
      Size = 50
    end
  end
  object DataSource1: TDataSource
    DataSet = ClientDataSet
    Left = 152
    Top = 88
  end
end
```

The bug happens after second click on ShowPanel.

Comment: Strange place to put a panel. It's a bug nevertheless.

Comment: The fact is, on delphi with "enable runtime theme" unchecked, it's works.

Comment: What kind of grid are you using exactly? Is the panel a child or sibling of the grid? It would help if you would provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating the problem.

Comment: @Remy - A string grid does fine. Panel is a sibling, grids don't have csAcceptControls by default.

Comment: @William: I was able to reproduce the issue with Delphi 10.0 Seattle. When using *any* custom style, the scrollbar is drawn on top of the Panel (the scrollbar is not responsive to the mouse within the panel's client area, so this is a drawing issue, the scrollbar is not actually on top of the panel).  When not using any style at all, just the standard Windows runtime theming, it works fine. This looks like a duplicate of the following bug: [RSP-10179: Incorrect painting of scroll bars for custom visual styles](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-10179)

Comment: Frankly, I would suggest just staying away from Styles altogether, they are *full* of bugs.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I'm using a DbGrid, and the panel is child of Dbgrid. And well, this panel is actually invisible, but there's a button to make it visible. When the panel becomes visible for the second time, this bug happens.

Comment: @William: again, can you please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](/help/mcve)?  When I make the Panel be a child of the grid, the problem does not happen anymore. Only when the Panel is a sibling that overlaps the grid.

Comment: @RemyLebeau i've just posted the code.

Comment: @William - Your panel is not a child of your grid.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz All forms in the main project where i work, are like that

Comment: @William: look at the DFM you showed. The two panels are not *children* of the grid, they are *siblings*.  That makes a big difference.  In any case, [this is a known bug](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-10179).

Comment: @RemyLebeau i just confound myself this time, anyway, i just can't make panel be child of dbgrid.

Comment: @William: Not at design-time, no, because the grid does not accept child controls being dropped on it in the Form Designer.  But since the grid is a `TWinControl` descendant , you can assign it to the `Parent` property of any child control at runtime.

Comment: @RemyLebeau imagine doing this in many forms...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way to "solve" this problem just changing grid `seBorder` to false, i used Notepad++ to locate in all project for ": TDBGrid"¹ and replace to ": TDBGrid StyleElements = [seFont, seClient]"¹. Isn't the better way to solve this problem i think, because changing `seBorder` to false will make the scrollbars style looks like the scrolls of your windows version.

---

¹ Ignore the quotes when you try to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can Define DBgrid as parent of your panel.

```
procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  panel1.Parent := dbgrid1;
  panel1.align := alBottom;
end;
```

Comment: It Works, but i was wanting to maintain the panel width.

Comment: You just have to define position of your panel. remove align property. keep only parent association.

Answer (score -1):

In fact, the only way is to work with the parent of the DBgrid.
This example work fine for me :

```
procedure TForm1.adjustPanelTo(const aPanel: TPanel; aWcontrol: TWinControl);
begin
  if aPanel = nil then Exit;
  if aWcontrol = nil then Exit;
  if aWcontrol.Parent = nil then Exit;

  aPanel.Parent := aWcontrol.Parent;
  aPanel.Anchors := [akLeft, akTop];
  aPanel.Left := aWcontrol.Left + 1;
  aPanel.Top := aWcontrol.Top + aWcontrol.ClientHeight - aPanel.Height;
  aPanel.BringToFront;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  adjustPanelTo(Panel1, DBGrid1);
end;
```

Comment: `Panel1.Top    := DBGrid1.ClientHeight - Panel1.Height;` That puts the panel to above the scroll bar, the scroll bar is part of the non-client area.

Comment: Of course you don't need to modify the parent if the solution is to move the panel upwards.

Comment: Have you tried to scroll the grid with the scrollbar, while the panel is visible? Does it work OK in your opinion? The `TDBGrid` is simply not designed to host child controls.

Comment: BringToFront seems to help here somehow. Let's see if it helps OP.

Comment: You need to change `aPanel.Top := aWcontrol.Top + aWcontrol.ClientHeight - aPanel.Height;` to `aPanel.Top := aWcontrol.Top + aWcontrol.Height - aPanel.Height;` though.